# presto + how to tune task.concurrency

Tags: presto

From presto document:

`task.concurrency` description:
https://prestosql.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html

```
    Type: integer
    Restrictions: must be a power of two
    Default value: 16
    Default local concurrency for parallel operators such as joins and aggregations. This value should be adjusted up or down based on the query concurrency and worker resource utilization. 
Lower values are better for clusters that run many queries concurrently because the cluster will already be utilized by all the running queries, so adding more concurrency will result in slow downs due to context switching and other overhead. Higher values are better for clusters that only run one or a few queries at a time. This can also be specified on a per-query basis using the task_concurrency session property.
```

from my understanding -  we need to set the `task.concurrency` according to `CPU cores X Number of Thread`

I will give example from lscpu on one of the presto worker machines

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    2
```

**because 16 X 2 = 32**

then from my understanding its should be `task.concurrency=32` ?

and this parameter should be configured only on `presto workers` in `config.properties` file

am I right here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is a bit complex.

The [`task.max-worker-threads`](https://trino.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#task-max-worker-threads) property is the number of threads that Presto will use to execute tasks for queries. This is a cooperative multi-tasking design where each task is expected to only use the thread for about a second before, returning to the scheduler.  As you might expect, this property is typically set relative to the number of CPU cores (current default is 2x the core count).

The [`task.concurrency`](https://trino.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#task-concurrency) property is the number of tasks that are generated for *worker parallel* tasks.  There are some worker tasks that are required to be single threaded. For example, a final `LIMIT` requires a single counter to restrict the number of rows to an exact count.  After a step like that, the planner can insert an worker-local exchange to allow for parallel execution of the next steps.  For these parallel steps, the system must choose a number to run in parallel, and this option controls that decision. For this property, the number isn't directly related to the number of cores, because the task scheduler mentioned above can handle many more tasks than cores, but in general you don't need have more than the core count.  A high value for `task.concurrency` can lead to inefficiency due to splitting the data in to very small chunks.  On the other hand, if the number is too low, you can increase query latency as everything waits for a few threads to process a lot of data.  Typically a value of 8 or 16 is good enough for more installations.

Comment: your final answer was - 8 or 16 is good enough for more installations. , let give example that we have each presto worker with 64 core X 2 Thread = 128 , so in this case , can we set the task.concurrency between 64-128 ?

Comment: It really depends. A number that large can result in worker data that is split too small, so the system spends a lot of CPU time moving around tiny bit of data.  This can cause an increase in CPU usage as overhead starts to dominate the execution.  If you want to be sure, you will need to benchmark some queries.  If you want a guess, I'd leave it at 16 or maybe increase to 32.